# Assign a Value to a New Field Depending on Which Existing Field Has A String Match

Tags: t-sql

My data looks something like the following

```
Col1    COl2    Col3    COl4    COl5
Yes     No      No      No      No
No      Yes     No      No      No
```

And I want to create a new column as follows:

```
Col1    COl2    Col3    COl4    COl5    NEW_FIELD
Yes     No      No      No      No      Col1
No      Yes     No      No      No      Col2
```

Whereby the new field takes the name of the field where 'Yes' is matched (it only occurs in one of the columns between Col1 and Col5).

I believe I can do this with a `CASE` function but as I have approximately 10 columns, the syntax gets a little unwieldy and i'm wondering if there is a cleaner `MIN()` type function across fields?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: A `case` _expression_ is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the first value using `coalesce()` and `case`:

```
select t.*,
       (coalesce(case when col1 = 'Yes' then 'col1' end,
                 case when col2 = 'Yes' then 'col2' end,
                 case when col3 = 'Yes' then 'col3' end,
                 case when col4 = 'Yes' then 'col4' end,
                 case when col5 = 'Yes' then 'col5' end
                )
        ) as new_field
```

Actually, `coalesce()` is not needed:

```
select t.*,
       (case when col1 = 'Yes' then 'col1'
             when col2 = 'Yes' then 'col2'
             when col3 = 'Yes' then 'col3'
             when col4 = 'Yes' then 'col4'
             when col5 = 'Yes' then 'col5'
        ) as new_field
```

This does not seem particularly "unwieldy".